# Can we use google cloud build on compute engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-build

I am following this link https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/quickstart-build and trying to understand how to use google cloud built to deploy code on a google compute engine.

I have created a repository on GitHub and already set up the cloud build by following link https://github.com/marketplace/google-cloud-build

For now, manually I have installed PHP, Apache on compute engine and hosted my code under /var/www/html and it is working.

So please suggest me the steps How can I achieve automated built deployment to compute engine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As it states, Cloud build is used to build docker images and then push them to Container Registry. If you want to use Compute Engine, then the OS image you should use on Compute Engine is Container Optimized OS. From there you can pull the image from Container Registry.